# Как задать стили определённому элементу при добавлении класса active к другому элементу?

Tags: css

Имеется следующая html структура:

```
<div class="fp=right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#head1" class="active"></a></li> // задать стили именно для li
            <li><a href="#head2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#head3"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#head4"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#head5"></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Нужно задать стили для первого элемента li, когда у ссылки внутри него появляется класс active

Comment: На CSS вроде никак, так как если не ошибаюсь, то селекторы работают только от родителя к дочернему элементу.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью JS можно добавить класс со стилями для `<li>`. Для обращения к родителю элемента необходимо использовать [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode). В демо-примере при клике на ссылку, ей добавляется класс `active`, а также её родителю класс `li-active`. Но если необходимо проанализировать элементы на наличие класса и после добавить стили родителю, то сделать это можно при помощи [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) вот так:

```
const link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

link.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.closest(".active")) {
    element.parentNode.classList.add("li-active");
  }
})
```

Демо:

```js
const link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

link.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    element.classList.add("active");
    element.parentNode.classList.add("li-active");
  });
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}

.li-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```